# Haskell: Creating Partial of Custom Data Type With Variables

Tags: haskell

I have a working function that uses guards to determine how to create a copy of a custom data type (in this case `Transaction`) yet change only one field in doing so. What is the idiomatic way to solve this issue?

If I could use variables as keys in my partials, I could simplify the function to something like the following:

```
change n val uid list = do
    let partial x = x {uid = uid, n = val}
    mergeData partial uid list
```

But I can't seem to find a way to use a variable as a key or call a function common to all guards.

```
change :: [Char] -> [Char] -> String -> [Transaction] -> IO ()
change n val uid list
    | n == "amount" = do
        let partial x = x {uid = (id uid), amount = (id val)}
        mergeData partial uid list
    | n == "user" = do
        let partial x = x {uid = (id uid), user = (id val)}
        mergeData partial uid list
    | n == "category" = do
        let partial x = x {uid = (id uid), user = (id val)}
        mergeData partial uid list
    | n == "description" = do
        let partial x = x {uid = (id uid), description = (id val)}
        mergeData partial uid list
```

P. S. `mergeData` is another function which is creating this copied instance of `Transaction` with the edited fields.

Comment: (Side note: what do you think `id` does?)

Comment: Now looking at it. I suppose it does nothing. In fact, my actual code doesn't have it so I don't know why I added it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) for that?

You'll need

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
```

and

```
import Control.Lens (makeLenses, (.~))
```

in your module file.

Then, guessing at what `Transaction` looks like, you could define it like this:

```
data Transaction = Transaction {
    _uid :: String
  , _amount :: String
  , _user :: String
  , _description :: String }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Transaction
```

This creates lenses called `uid`, `amount`, and so on.

You can now simplify the `change` function to this:

```
change' :: (Transaction -> Transaction) -> String -> [Transaction] -> IO ()
change' l uidValue = mergeData ((uid .~ uidValue) . l) uidValue
```

For testing, I first defined `mergeData` like this, as it seems to fit the type used in the OP `change` function:

```
mergeData :: (Transaction -> Transaction) -> String -> [Transaction] -> IO ()
mergeData f _ = mapM_ (print . f)
```

Here are some examples:

```
λ> ts = [Transaction "1" "42" "Joan" "Foo", Transaction "2" "1337" "Nigel" "Bar"]
λ> change' (amount .~ "0") "7" ts
Transaction {_uid = "7", _amount = "0", _user = "Joan", _description = "Foo"}
Transaction {_uid = "7", _amount = "0", _user = "Nigel", _description = "Bar"}
λ> change' (user .~ "Jane") "7" ts
Transaction {_uid = "7", _amount = "42", _user = "Jane", _description = "Foo"}
Transaction {_uid = "7", _amount = "1337", _user = "Jane", _description = "Bar"}
```

As you can see, `amount .~ "0"` sets all the `_amount` labels to `"0"`, and `user .~ "Jane"` sets all `_user` labels to `"Jane"`. Both expressions have the type `Transaction -> Transaction`:

```
λ> :type amount .~ "0"
amount .~ "0" :: Transaction -> Transaction
λ> :type user .~ "Jane"
user .~ "Jane" :: Transaction -> Transaction
```

If you don't like the underscores in record labels, you can use `makeLensesFor` instead of `makeLenses`.

Comment: Fantastic. This works great. I think I will adapt it to only set a specific record instead of all records, but this gives me enough to get there.